# How to achieve single logout through configured cas client?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cas

I am using apereo CAS server single sign on for multiple application.single sign on is configured successful at at my end but i am not able to achieve single logout. 
so may i know the logout configuration for the same.

using apereo cas version : 5.3.9

note[client application is developed using spring mvc and now i want single sign in and logout for the same. not getting proper hints through net.]

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Which cas client are you using?

Comment: CAS client application developed using spring mvc.

Comment: Check the documentation for [Single Logout](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Logout-Single-Signout.html).

Comment: sorry, not geeting the documentation. in my spring mvc project not able to achieve it. i have two application developed in spring mvc. i have achived single sign in through apereo cas server version 5.X. if there is any working example link den it will help better.thanx in advance.

Comment: I am using [java cas client](https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client). It's quite easy to setup. You have to add some cas specific filters and  the library handles the rest. For single logout, check `SingeSignOutFilter` from provided link.

Comment: I already have my project developed in spring mvc. i have added required configuratin in web.xml. may u show me your logout controller of your application and web.xml.